# Will a single webapp reload pick up a modified Tomcat setenv.sh?

Tags: java, tomcat

Is it possible to modify Tomcat environment variables and have them picked up by a single reloaded webapp without restarting the whole server?

Let's say we have webapp A and B, and a `setenv.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_DIR=/var/srv
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_45
TOMCAT_DIR=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.18
TOMCAT_PORT=8080
SOME_PROPERTY=SOMETHING
```

If we change `SOME_PROPERTY` and reload only A, will it catch the new values, or do we need to restart Tomcat?

Comment: Is the script `setenv.sh` being ever executed?

Comment: Yes, why wouldnt it?

Comment: Is it executed when you reload a webapp, or only when tomcat is (re)started?

Comment: The script is definitely executed on (re)start. However, I'm not sure what the behaviour is or should be for app reload. I would assume that a webapp process is initially spawned with the environment variables and not changed afterwards. Maybe only on reload? I was hoping to find out here, as I couldn't find any docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setenv.sh` is not just a configuration file that is read. It is a script that is executed before the tomcat JVM is started, for setting the environment for the tomcat JVM process (a process for the underlying OS). Once that process is started, it is running in a context with this environment variables.

Java can access and mutate system properties (`-D` parameters to the JVM command line, not to be confused with env variables) through `System.getProperty` and `System.setProperty` but it won't be able, on its own, to parse and interpret the shell script(s) that were used to start the JVM process on the host OS.

My suggestion is to create a configuration file, pass the path to this configuration file in an env variable / system property, and reload this file on application startup.

Comment: You think it's possible to pass env variables on a per-webapp basis?

Comment: Yes if the apps are looking for different variable names, that is definitely possible: `APP1_CONFIG=X` `APP2_CONFIG=Y`

Comment: @frhd Environment variables are available to the whole process, not targeted at a single web application running on the JVM. As *dotvav* says, you can use an environment variable that only the target web application would recognize, but that's kind of ugly. Use of environment variables in Java is discouraged in favor of using system properties instead, which are mutable at runtime (as mentioned in this answer).

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation the `setenv.sh` script is listed as a run at startup script. So, you're going to need to restart Tomcat for changes to take hold.